# traceroute in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping, traceroute

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and I don't have `traceroute`, even I've just done,

```
sudo apt-get install traceroute
```

So I checked, and indeed traceroute package don't have traceroute program:

```
$ dpkg -L traceroute
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/lft.db
/usr/bin/traceproto.db
/usr/bin/traceroute-nanog
/usr/bin/traceroute.db
/usr/include
/usr/include/clif.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libsupp.a
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/tcptraceroute.db
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/traceroute
/usr/share/doc/traceroute/CREDITS
/usr/share/doc/traceroute/README
/usr/share/doc/traceroute/TODO
/usr/share/doc/traceroute/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/traceroute/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/traceroute.db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/bin/traceroute6.db
/usr/share/man/man1/lft.db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/traceproto.db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/traceroute-nanog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/traceroute6.db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/tcptraceroute.db.8.gz
```

How to do traceroute then?
I remember that `ping` can do it, but didn't find that in a rush.

I do have `traceroute6` but, don't know how to use it:

```
$ traceroute6 172.217.2.165
traceroute: 172.217.2.165: Address family for hostname not supported
```

FTR,

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, right here:

```
/usr/bin/traceroute.db
```

There are [several](https://wiki.geant.org/display/public/EK/Traceroute+LikeTools) traceroute programs for Linux; this is "Traceroute by **D**mitry **B**utskoy". Your own file list also shows a script `/usr/bin/traceroute-nanog` that emulates "NANOG Traceroute".

You can also find *inetutils-traceroute*, *iputils-tracepath*, *mtr*, and *dublin-traceroute*.

Note: Debian and Ubuntu have a mechanism called "update-alternatives" which is supposed to pick the best program version out of the ones which are installed, and automatically symlink it to the common `/usr/bin/traceroute` name. It seems that this mechanism is broken on your system.

Comment: I have discovered `mtr` (in like-named package) which is a very cool combined ping/tracetroute and since then I no longer use traceroute.

Answer (score 0):

try:
sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute